# MS Word like template for LaTeX?

Tags: sectioning, color, themes, msword

I need the format of the section titles to match with the default ones used in MS Word (actually with a bit different coloring), but I can't really find a way to change specificly the sections' format.
What is the way of doing this?

(my LaTeX docs should look like some previously written Word docs)

What I have:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{enumerate}          
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}        
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ a4paper, top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{roboto}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{47,84,150}
\definecolor{midblue}{RGB}{0,112,192}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{0,176,240}

\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
\chapterfont{\color{darkblue}}
\sectionfont{\color{darkblue}}
\subsectionfont{\color{midblue}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{lightblue}}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Chap}
    \section{lvl1}
    \subsection{lvl2}
    \subsubsection{lvl3}

\end{document}
```

What I want:

[image]

edit: I figured out coloring, added pictures and code, I'm using MikTex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: To be more specific, what you are missing is the indentation of the subsection header, right? Or do you also want to reduce the spacing between the section headers?

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of writing `top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in`, one could write more concisely `vmargin=1in, hmargin=1.25in`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The most important points are these: font type, indentation and bold text.

Comment: That solution gives me error because I use miktex, I think it should be possible to do it with miktex

Comment: It has nothing to do with the distribution, but the compiler…

Comment: @TeXnician what is the difference between distribution and compiler? I searched before asking, and found out that MikTex is referenced as compiler and distribution too.

Comment: No, MikTeX is no compiler. pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and some others are compilers and you will use one of them. MikTeX is the distribution, i.e. through MikTeX's package management compilers, packages etc. are installed on your machine.